# Database query using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm new here.. I just want to ask on how to compare a user input from the value taken from the a specific table in the database..

Like for instance.. I have a table named sample which has 3 fields namely ID, WebsiteName, IpAddress..

Sample value:

```
1   www.google.com 192.168.1.1
2   www.yahoo.com  198.178.3.2
```

I have a form wherein a user will input the name of the website and the program will then get its corresponding IP address by using gethostbyname function in php.. What I want is the program should check in the database if the website entered by the user is already in the database. Once found it will then check if the corresponding ip address stored in the database is the same with the result using the gethostbyname function in php... And it will just display some message like ip address didn't match or ip address match..

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a MySQL-db you can use [mysql_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to connect to your db, and then [mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to run your SQL. Make sure to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the data input by the user before using it in your SQL-statement, to sanitize it and protect your db against SQL-injections.

It would probably look something like this in your case:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["someinput"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE WebsiteName = '$input'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // Do what you want to do when the website exist in db
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```